# Removing all fragments with same tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

I open new fragments with this :

```
fragment = new Frag_Business_Dialog();  
fragment.setArguments(bundle); 
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).add(R.id.mainContent, fragment,"mesaj_chat").commit();
```

and i remove them by this on button press:

```
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mesaj_chat")).commit();
```

My app can open one or two... or many same fragments. And i want to remove all of them with the same tag by one line of code ( one press of a button ). With the code above i remove one by one. How can i tag all this fragments and remove them at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but I'd say keep the count of how many fragments you have and then loop on this count to remove all the fragments one by one.